# IOS passing backslash as part of url parameter to Json Web Service

Tags: ios, json, http, parameters

I'm calling a Json Web Service wich expects two parameters. username and password.
The username I'm trying to pass includes a backslash (`\`) as it is a domain account eg. `companyname\jamesd`.

Here is my code.

```
NSString *sName = @"companyname\\jamesd";

NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://checkin.companyname.com:2002/Checkin.svc/checklogin?username=%@&password=pass",sName];
```

Problem is the backslash is somehow removed when calling the web service -

I use `NSLog(...)` to output what the request looks like -

```
<NSURLRequest http://checkin.companyname.com:2002/Checkin.svc/checklogin?username=companynamejamesd&password=pass>
```

I'm trying to find out how I can force include the backslash in the http request for the username.

Comment: You need to url-encode the arguments. There are many previous questions on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like  `Mike Weller` stated in the comment you have to url-encode the arguments. You should use the `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method of NSString after you create the url string something like:

```
NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://checkin.companyname.com:2002/Checkin.svc/checklogin?username=%@&password=pass",sName];
URL = [URL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You can change the encoding to as you want, check the iOS encoding on [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Also make sure that you are adding the backslash when you're creating the url string.